# rail 3.2: how do I use number helpers or application helpers inside a custom helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper

I have a custom helper module, CalendarHelper. Some of my views then use custom helper methods to display a calendar.

When I try to use any view helpers inside my custom helpers, such as number_to_currency(), I get an undefined method error, even if I add

```
include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
```

to my CalendarHelper.

I also tried adding a method to application_helper:

```
  def as_dollars_pretty(price)
    number_to_currency(price, :precision => 2, :unit => '$')
  end
```

then in my custom helper I added

```
include ApplicationHelper
```

but when I try to use as_dollars_pretty(123.45) in my custom calendar helper I get the same undefined method error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me

```
module TestHelper
  include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper

  def foo
    number_to_currency 123
  end
end

include TestHelper

puts foo
```

Comment: You are right, I have code working in ApplicationController while I remembered it was ApplicationHelper.

Comment: I dunno, tried that first, didn't work, tried it again after you answered the question and now it works. Must have had a typo first time around.

Comment: This is usable for any other helper, just keep in mind the classes organisation. Blah::Something::Crazy